# How to fetch google Analytics data without polling

Tags: java, analytics, webhooks, google-analytics-firebase

I have configured Google Analytics on my Website. I want to fetch customer information like *session duration* by hitting the [Google Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) but only way I can find to do that is to *poll* this API after every given time which I found is not a right thing to do so I searched other work arounds and I got to know about **Web Hooks** through [this](https://thenewstack.io/wonderful-world-webhooks/) link.

So anyone can guide how to hit this API in an efficient manner?
Thank You!

Comment: Google Analytics does not offer any webhooks.

Comment: So is there any other way to avoid polling? @dmulter

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Unless you need real-time or up to the minute data, GA data doesn't change so you could store or cache historic data if performance is your major concern. If yesterday's data is good enough, say, you can probably pull the data once per day with a scheduled task.

Comment: @TheLyrist no actually i want real time data. On understanding each user behaviour (like if his/her session duration has exceeded 5 min) then I want to pop up a live chat to that user who has visited my website.

Comment: Hi Aadit, if that's your use case, GA could be overkill and it might not be the best tool for that job. Perhaps you can consider using screen time tracking tools designed for UX tracking, etc. such as https://screentime.parsnip.io etc. (I use the plugin but am not affiliated with the free tool)

Comment: @TheLyrist oh I see, it is a great tool. But what If i want to know other details like customer's geolocation, customer total sessions and other behavioural aspects of that user?

Comment: You don’t get the individual geolocation and behavioural data from GA either. It is all aggregated.

Comment: @TheLyrist Oh I see actually I don't know much about GA. Thank you for clearing my doubts. Much appreciated